# Create a new column in a calendar programatically

Tags: development, calendar, column

When a new item is added to the event list, I would like to:

1. Verify if the new column already exists
2. If not create a new hyperlink column.

I am not sure how to do this by code using SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SPList list = web.Lists["MyList"];

if (!list.Fields.ContainsField("MyColumn"))
{
        // create Text type new column called "MyColumn"
    list.Fields.Add("MyColumn", SPFieldType.URL, true);

    // make new column visible in default view
    SPView view = list.DefaultView;
    view.ViewFields.Add("MyColumn");
    view.Update();
}
```